# grails 2.1.0 Chained select relation

Tags: grails, grails-2.0, grails-domain-class, grails-controller

I want to make chain select box in my view page. I have country select box, and city select box. And in city domain I have country id. Now I want to show cities of a specific country when I select a country. But I have no idea. I am using grails 2.1.0. I have googled on this and tried some codes. But no result. I am giving my domain, controller and view. How can I make the event onchange, create a list of city with the country_id and show it in the city select box? Can anyone please help me on this please ?

my country domain >>>

```
    package com

class Country {

     String name
    String abbr
    String language

static hasMany = [cities:City]

    static constraints = {
    }
}
```

my city domain >>>

```
    package com

class City {

   String name 
   String timezone

static belongsTo = [country:Country]

    static constraints = {
    }
}
```

my country controller >>>

```
package com

import com.City
class CountryController {

    def index = { }

}
```

my view page >>>

```
<%@ page import="com.Country; com.City" %>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <meta name="layout" content="country" />
</head>
<body>
  <form>
    <g:select
      optionKey="id" optionValue="name" id="countryname" name="countryname"  from="${Country.list()}">
    </g:select>
    <g:select optionKey="id" optionValue="name" id="cityname" name="cityname" from="${City.list()}"></g:select>
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is there anybody who can create a chain select with the source code above ?

Answer (score 1):

Try making an Ajax call to fetch the cities for a given country.

See this similar SO question : [Populate dropdown list using ajax In grails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7156436/populate-dropdown-list-using-ajax-in-grails)