# Grails chain selects without domains

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, grails

I'm trying to chain two, possibly three `<g:select ...>` statements together using Ajax like is shown here [Populate dropdown list using ajax In grails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7156436/populate-dropdown-list-using-ajax-in-grails) but all the examples I find have two big differences from what I'm using. 1. I'm using the jQuery library, not prototype. And 2. I don't have domain objects for my select values, they are pulled from an Oracle table via a service call.

My problem looks like this:

```
<g:select name="degreeSubject" from="${majors}" noSelection="${['':'-Choose Subject-']}" value="${degreeInstance?.degreeSubject }"/>
<g:select name="degreeConcentration" from="${concentrations}" noSelection="${['':'']}" value="${degreeInstance?.degreeConcentration }"/>
```

Where the majors, and concentrations come through the controller but are populated in a service class.

I was thinking the controller method would look something like

```
def updateSelect = {
    def concentrations = degreeService.getConcentrations(params.selectedValue)
    render (template:"selectConcentration", model : ['concentrations' : concentrations])

}
```

But, I can't get it to work.

Thoughts? Or someone have an example of doing this with jQuery and no domain objects using Grails 2.2.4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can really do it without being javascript-library specific.  If you use the grails built-in remoteFunction it will handle the jQuery portion for you.  What you would then want for your degreeSubject select is:

```
<g:select name="degreeSubject" 
          from="${majors}" 
          noSelection="${['':'-Choose Subject-']}" 
          value="${degreeInstance?.degreeSubject }"
          onChange="${remoteFunction(
            controller: 'yourControllerName', 
            action: 'updateSelect', 
            params: '\'value=\' + escape(this.value),
            onSuccess: 'updateConcentration(data)')}/>
```

The key being the onChange event calling the remoteFunction.  The remote function will make an ajax call to whatever controller action you want, but you'll need to call a javascript function to take in the results of your controller action and populate the other select.  If you wanted to do this with simple js you could do this:

```
function updateConcentration(items) {
    var control = document.getElementById('degreeConcentration')

    // Clear all previous options
    var i = control.length
    while (i > 0) {
        i--
        control.remove(i)
    }

    // Rebuild the select
    for (i=0; i < items.length; i++) {
        var optItem = items[i]
        var opt = document.createElement('option');
        opt.text = optItem.value
        opt.value = optItem.id
        try {
                control.add(opt, null) // doesn't work in IE
        }
        catch(ex) {
                control.add(opt) // IE only
        }
    }
}
```

and finally your controller action should look like this:

```
def updateSelect(value) = {
    def concentrations = degreeService.getConcentrations(value)
    render concentrations as JSON // or use respond concentrations if you upgrade to 2.3
}
```

Comment: In your javascript, what is item? And where does it come from?

Comment: Good question.  It's a typing error :).  The items collection represents the concentrations coming back from the controller action.

Comment: Got it about an 2 hours ago. It's working just like it should!