# Grails 2.4.2 Ajax not working for OnChange

Tags: ajax, grails, grails-2.4

I have to dynamically load a set of values based on the value i chose in another drop down.

In Controller I have the following code,

```
def ajaxGetCities(params){

println params.id
def userCustPlantDetails = utilitySummaryService.fetchUserCustPlantDetails('PHILL00')

def data = []
userCustPlantDetails?.get('UserPlantList').collect{
        data << it.pwr_plt_nme
}

[data: data]

}
```

In gsp I have :

```
 <g:select class="btn btn-default" name="viewValue" from="${view}" onchange="${remoteFunction(
        action:'ajaxGetCities', 
        params:'\'id=\' + escape(this.value)', 
        onSuccess :'updateCity(data)')}"></g:select>
```

When I change the value of dropdown , i see the trigger and controller action is called. Post that Javascript updateCity is not responding. What am I missing ? What is the difference between onComplete and OnSuccess.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18925786/grails-chain-selects-without-domains (Possible Duplicate) Solved my problem. I'm supposed to return as JSON. Is my understanding correct ?

Comment: I believe RemoteFunction may also be deprecated and that's not how you use collect.  Should be:  def data = userCustPlantDetails?.get('UserPlantList').collect{ it.pwr_plt_nme }